# Login failed after Liferay version upgrade from 5.2.3 to 6.0

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

After upgradation of liferay unable to login. Main issue what I figured out is Screen-Name (for any user) is changed when user attempt to login.

e.g. suppose ScreenName in database is "sunil" and when I attempt for login it is changed to "sunil.1".

Comment: If I am changing the "Screen-Name" manually in the MySql sometime I am able to login. i.e if I change the ID from "sunil.1" to "sunil" then it is logged in fine sometime.

Comment: Can anyone share his/her experience regarding what is the common problem for login issue after upgrade ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reply on Linkedin and the problem is due to LDAP integration. To get rid of this error I have added "users.screen.name.always.autogenerate=false" in "portal-ext.properties" file. Ultimately I am able to do the Liferay core from 5.2 to 6.0 version successfully :)